# Is the $1$ of ring the $1$ of subring?

Tags: ring-theory

In the definition of subring, it is no necessary that $1$ is in the subring. For example, consider the ring $G=\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ and subring $H=2\mathbb{Z}_{10}.$ In this case, $6$ is the new $1$.

Comment: What is your definition of subring? In the one I know, $1$ is required by definition to be in each subring. This implies, for example, that proper ideals are not subrings!

Comment: (If $G$ is commutative) then this can happen iff $G$ is a product of two rings: the 1 of the subring  is an element of $G$ such that $e\ne 0,1, e^2=e$ then $G= e G \times (1-e) G$.

Comment: @J126 But $3 \not\in 2\mathbf Z_{10}$

Comment: @J126 6 is the 1 in the subring $2\mathbb{Z_{10}}$ because $6\cdot2k = 12k=2k$

Comment: @Compacto maybe that it is an additive subgroup and closed under multiplication, so that 1 is not necessary in the subring, so that all ideals are examples of subrings?

Comment: See this post, then: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/523832/if-a-subring-of-a-ring-r-has-identity-does-r-also-have-the-identity?rq=1  The zero subring (which I would have excluded) has zero as identity.

Answer (score 2):

This is a language issue - in a technical sense of "language." There are **two** ways to think of a unital ring:

- As a set $X$ equipped with a pair of binary operations $\oplus,\odot$ such that [stuff].
- As a set $X$ equipped with a pair of binary operations $\oplus,\odot$ *and* a distinguished element (or nullary function) $\mathbb{1}$ such that [stuff].

Call these "weak" and "strong" unital rings, respectively. We actually have a couple more options than this, but this turns out to be a sufficient amount of variety *([pun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_(universal_algebra)) intended - and relevant, see below!)* to consider. We then have:

- If $X$ is a sub-*strong*-unital-ring of $Y$ then the multiplicative identities of $X$ and $Y$ are the same since that's built right into the definition of sub-thing.
- If $X$ is merely a sub-*weak*-unital-ring of $Y$ then the multiplicative identities of $X$ and $Y$ need not coincide (e.g. consider the zero ring as a sub-weak-unital-ring of your favorite nonzero unital ring).

Now typically when we say "subring" in the unital context, we're talking about unital rings in the strong sense and hence we mean the strong subring notion. Note that weak unital rings **do not** form a variety in the sense of universal algebra - see the link above - so there is some heuristic reason to do this.

Comment: Though of course in the second sense we have a unary operation and another distinguished element/nullary operation related to the additive structure, though it is not necessary to consider that for the issue at hand. +1